# Java - What is wrong with this variable initialisation code?

Tags: java, integer, rounding

I've written the following, but Java doesn't like it!

```
int limit = Math.round(Math.sqrt(inputNumber));
```

Suggestions from my IDE are to add a cast of `(int)` to the right hand side, but I was under the impression that `Math.round` would format the number into an integer anyway?

Comment: Just look at the documentation, sqrt returns double, round(double) returns long..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.sqrt(x)` returns a `double`. There are several overloaded `Math.round` functions. The one that takes a `double` as the argument returns a `long`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

See the API of [java.lang.Math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

> static long : round(double a)
>  static int : round(float a)
>
> static double : sqrt(double a)

Math.sqrt returns a **double**.
When you send a double to Math.round, it returns a **long**.
So, `Math.round(Math.sqrt(inputNumber))` return a long, and you must cast it to integer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Math.sqrt` returns a `double`, the version of `Math.round` gets called which returns a `long`, but you want to put it into an `int`, thus the IDE suggestion.